# ¿Cómo arreglar el error de Dompdf: Image not found or type unknown?

Tags: php, html, dompdf

Genero reportes usando Dompdf (1.2.0) pero no muestras las imágenes que tengo.

***MI FUNCION PHP:***

```
<?php
    require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';  
    use Dompdf\Dompdf; 

    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $html = file_get_contents("../Vista/pdfpruebacot.php"); 
    
    $dompdf->set_option( 'dpi' , '120' );
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html); 
    $dompdf->set_paper('letter', 'portrait');
    
    $options = $dompdf->getOptions();
    $options->setIsHtml5ParserEnabled(true);
    $options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);

    $dompdf->setOptions($options);
    $dompdf->render();

    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=documento.pdf");
    echo $dompdf->output();
?>
```

***EL HTML DE MI REPORTE:***

```
<img src="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?> /portallavemi/images/logo LAVEMI.png" width="100px" height="100px">
```

***YA INTENTE:***

- Cambiar el "extension=gd" en mi Xampp

***MI ERROR:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ***GRACIAS.***

Comment: Utiliza la URL completa (`http`), no el path de directorio

Comment: Has conseguido solucionar el problema? Podrias indicar como? En caso de que no, te invito a probar escribiendo la ruta completa desde el disco en tu ordenador: `c:/xampp/htdocs/portallavemi/images/logo LAVEMI.png`. Se tiene que pasar el path en el disco en vez de la URL

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require_once 'Libraries/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

/*En esta linea de código mandamos a llamar las opciones de dpmpdf para 
usarlas al momento de usar imágenes */
use Dompdf\Options;

ob_start();

<html>
    Cuerpo de html a convertir en pdf
</html>

$html=ob_get_clean();

//Aquí se crea el objeto a utilizar
$options = new Options();

//Y debes activar esta opción "TRUE"
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled', TRUE);

$dompdf = new DOMPDF($options);


$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("dsdsds.pdf", array("Attachment"=>false));

//Fijate en el encabezado y en el footer del código

?>
```

Todo esto ya debes de tener la opción de extension=gd activada en tu Xampp