# DomPDF Image not found or type unknown en PHP

Tags: php, html, dompdf

Tengo la siguiente grafica dentro de un HTML, que después convierto a PDF (utilizando la librería DomPDF) en PHP:

```
https://quickchart.io/chart?c={type:'line',data:{labels:['ENE','FEB','MAR','ABR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AGO','SEP','OCT','NOV','DIC'],datasets:[{label:'OperacionesXMes',data:[5,30,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],backgroundColor:'rgb(255, 255, 255)',borderColor:'rgb(255, 0, 0)',borderWidth:2}]},options:{scales:{y:{beginAtZero:true}},plugins:{legend:false}}}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al ver el PDF generado, me sale el error:

> *Image not found or type unknown.*

¿Podrían ayudarme a desplegar la grafica en el PDF?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/520625/c%C3%B3mo-arreglar-el-error-de-dompdf-image-not-found-or-type-unknown